# docker php:7.4-apache container, unable to get the page pull up in localhost

Tags: php, docker, dockerfile, docker-build, docker-run

i successfully created a php_apache image by going to the specified directory with following command
**docker build -t php_apache**

**my docker file is**

```
FROM php:7.4-apache
COPY Php_demo_project/ var/www/html/
EXPOSE 80
```

but while running the image with following command

```
docker run -it --rm --name php_demo_container -p 80:80 php_apache
```

am unable to get the page in browser, and when I search for localhost 404 forbidden access like showing
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RNuiv.png)

when I enter localhost in chrome in command line it is showing as

```
[Wed Jun 24 01:29:19.895025 2020] [autoindex:error] [pid 16] [client 172.17.0.1:42010] AH01276: Cannot serve directory /var/www/html/: No matching DirectoryIndex (index.php,index.html) found, and server-generated directory index forbidden by Options directive
```

172.17.0.1 - - [24/Jun/2020:01:29:19 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 403 491 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.116 Safari/537.36"

am unable to find where the error is..
what am I missing?????????

Comment: can you try  COPY Php_demo_project/*  var/www/html/
i mean, instead of copying whole folder, just copy the folder content to var/www/html

Comment: @TayburRahaman , again not showing the page in browser after writing COPY Php_demo_project/* var/www/html/

Answer (score 1):

I think this will help you:

```
FROM php:7.4-apache
COPY Php_demo_project/ /var/www/html
RUN chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www
EXPOSE 80
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your files have read access rights:

```sh
FROM php:7.4-apache
COPY Php_demo_project/ /var/www/html/
RUN chmod -R a+r /var/www/html/
EXPOSE 80
```

Comment: is there any manual permissions needed for chrome browser and docker

Comment: my index.php file is present in Php_demo_project/src but i mention only Php_demo_project not  Php_demo_project/src ,that's why the browser not found my index.php file and it is showing as forbidden access.                                                                         after writing COPY Php_demo_project/src in docker file the web page is showing in browser. thank you......

Comment: That makes sense too. Glad you fixed it!